# Listing all products in 1 row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database which has a table of products. Users can pick those products and they can put them in their cart, but because each organisation has their own prices they will be put into a `ProductCartLine` like this:

| CartId | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I want to convert this to something like

| CartId | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 3,4 |

The last column doesn't have to be 1 column, it can all be different columns, but everything needs to be in 1 row. I can't quite figure out how to group everything together.

How do I do this in a T-SQL statement, or do I need to process this afterwards in code?

Comment: Because it's a whole different cart with it's own lines

Comment: In the second table 2 row, the CartId should be 2.

Comment: You guys are right, I updated it

Comment: Don't do this. It's **very poor practice** to store multiple comma (or other delimiter) separated values in a single database field. You _can_ aggregate your data like this for a query (look at `string_agg`), but for the love of God don't design the table structure this way.

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn, I don't know whether you mean I shouldn't design it in the way as the first table or the second table. It's currently designed like in the first table, because the second one is practically not possible for me. But if I shouldn't do that, would you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want string aggregation:

```
select cartid,
    string_agg(productid, ',') within group(order by productid) as productids
from mytable
group by cartid
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. It's still isn't fully what I want, because the formatting is a bit weird, but I will handle that in code. I will mark this as the answer as soon as the button is available.